# Best Practice - Link to lib or compile source in Unit-Tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake

I want to ask what your experience is with getting the tested Source in your Unit-Test Application. Following structure

```
NiceLib
|-src
   |- MyNiceClass.h
   |- MyNiceClass.cpp
   |- CMakeLists.txt
|-test
   |- tester_MyNiceClass.cpp
   |- main.cpp
   |- CMakeLists.txt
```

In src a Library get compiled. In test a Test executable get builded. What is the best practice to get the implementation of MyNiceClass.cpp in your test application. At the moment I know two Options. Option one is to link against the library in the test executable. The test\CMakeLists.txt would look like:

```
enable_testing()

include_directories(../src/)

add_executable(tester_NiceLib
   main.cpp
   tester_MyNiceClass.cpp
   )

add_test(NicLibTest tester_NiceLib)

target_link_libraries(tester_NiceLib NiceLib)
```

The second solution is:

```
enable_testing()

include_directories(../src/)

add_executable(tester_NiceLib
   main.cpp
   tester_MyNiceClass.cpp

   ../src/MyNiceClass.h
   ../src/MyNiceClass.cpp
   )

add_test(NicLibTest tester_NiceLib)
```

What is your experience?Have you any Best-Practices or maybe other solutions?

Comment: Tend to believe, opinions might differ a bit. I will go for the linking with the library

Comment: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Answer (score 7):

> What is your experience?Have you any Best-Practices or maybe other solutions?

I use ***both variants*** (successfully), but ***which one suits best depends on the situation***. If you just need a single class, but your library contains a fair amount of other stuff, it may be an overkill. There's no general *"best solution"*.

Personally I recommend you to simply choose what suits best for your needs. It's no problem to switch between both at any later time.

However, better *don't* integrate *plain source files* to the tests, as they have to get compiled several times (for each test + the productive code). You can simply include the actual *Object files* instead and compile just once. This also gives you more flexibility and better dependency management of CMake.

Therefore, here are my two variants I use:

### Option 1: Link library

This is same as your first option.

**Build library:**

```
add_library(dependencies-lib Src1.cpp Src2.cpp)
```

**Link to the tests:**

```
# create test target ...
add_executable(exampletest SomeTests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exampletest dependencies-lib)
```

### Option 2: Add object library

This is almost the same as *Option 1*, but you can be very selective. However, it prevents the multiple compilation of the *plain source files method*.

**Build an Object library:**

```
add_library(dependencies-lib OBJECT Src1.cpp Src2.cpp)
#                            ^^^^^^
```

**Add objects to the tests:**

```
# create test target ...
add_executable(exampletest SomeTests.cpp 
                        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:dependencies-lib> # <-- !!
                        )
```

As you can see, you don't link it as a library, you use the compiled object files instead. Even if many other targets need these, they are compiled *only once*. Btw. you can easily pack them into a ordinary library / executable (eg. for the productive binary / lib):

```
add_library(all-together-lib Source1.cpp
                Source2.cpp
                # ...

                $<TARGET_OBJECTS:dependencies-lib>
                $<TARGET_OBJECTS:dependencies-lib2>
                $<TARGET_OBJECTS:dependencies-lib3>
                $<TARGET_OBJECTS:dependencies-and-many-more>
                # ...

                # And some more source files ...
                Example1.cpp
                Example2.cpp
                # ...
                )
```

#### Documentation

- [**add_library()**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html)

  - *Section:* [**Normal Libraries**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#normal-libraries)
  - *Section:* [**Object Libraries**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries)